# Hide Keyboard when click over the listview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

i am having a search view and a list view below that contains some data when i tap on the search view key board open which is so obvious but i want to hide the keyboard when user just tap on search view and does not type anything in the search view i want hide it when user click on the list view present below.

I am pretty sure that i am not able to clarify the question that's why i am adding some snap shots. [image: Normal Condition] [image: Hide Keyboard]

> Here when user tap on search view knowingly or unknowingly and does not write anything and just want to scroll the list view below i want that keyboard hides here when he start scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to hide your keyboard

```
public static void hideKeyboard( Context context ) {

    try {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = ( InputMethodManager ) context.getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE );

        View view = ( ( Activity ) context ).getCurrentFocus();
        if ( view != null ) {
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow( view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS );
        }
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Assuming your `listview` is `lv`

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
          hideKeyboard();
     }
});
```

Comment: yes i know about this method where i should add this

Comment: You need to implement the `setOnItemClickListener()` which fires when an item is clicked on said ListView.

Comment: In a utils class under a static definition is where the method for hideKeyboard should live, and for setting the click listener, do it in the activity that uses your listview in the onCreate method

Comment: #Murtaza hideKeyboard() method expecting context , and i am using fragment means my class extending fragment

Comment: use `getActivity()` for the context.

Comment: Seems a good method, but if you have 30 buttons ... you spend 30 "hideKeyboard();" ... can you provide any solution best ?  (Note my app have about 180-200 buttons ( optimized and looks great style) )

Comment: You can wrap that in a container and and add event there

Comment: Didn't get that.  What actual problem you are facing.?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to hide softkey immediately after the user touches the listView. Just attach an [OnFocusChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener) to the ListView like that:

```
    myListView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(((Activity) mContext).getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });
```